# Spark SQL - Insert only to 2 columns in a table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have following table created in spark SQL

```
create table if not exists my_db.fire_service_calls_tbl(
          CallNumber integer, 
          UnitID string,
          IncidentNumber integer,
          CallType string,
          CallDate string,
          WatchDate string,
          AvailableDtTm string,
          Address string,
          City string,
          CallFinalDisposition string,
          ZipCode integer,
          Neighborhood string,
          Location_Name string,
          RowID string
          ) using parquet
```

When I try to insert only to two columns, I am getting an error about a column that I have not referred in INSERT.

```
INSERT INTO my_db.fire_service_calls_tbl(CallNumber, UnitID) VALUES (1234,"aaa")
```

ERROR:

```
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name `IncidentNumber` cannot be resolved. Did you mean one of the following? [`CallNumber`, `UnitID`].;
```

I don't see this approach in [INSERT INTO](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/sql-ref-syntax-dml-insert-into.html) documentation

How to fix this?  If this is not supported in Spark SQL, why is it not supported such a basic SQL feature?

Note: I am running this in Databricks as part of trying to learn spark SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: starting from Spark 3.4.0 this limitation no longer exists.*

From the docs you linked:

> Note:The current behaviour has some limitations:
>
> - All specified columns should exist in the table and not be duplicated from each other. It includes all columns except the static partition columns.

This means that if you provide the column list you cannot skip any columns. This does makes it pretty useless, the only thing it allows is changing the order of the columns provided:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (a INT, b INT, c INT);
INSERT INTO foo (c, b, a) VALUES (3, 2, 1);
SELECT * FROM foo;
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
+---+---+---+
```

With DataFrame API I find myself quite frequently generating missing columns as nulls using something like:

```scala
val df = Seq(1).toDF("a")
val missingColumns = spark.table("foo").columns diff df.columns
val alignedDf = missingColumns.foldLeft(df) { case (acc, c) => acc.withColumn(c, lit(null)) }
alignedDf.insertInto("foo")
spark.table("foo").show
+---+----+----+
|  a|   b|   c|
+---+----+----+
|  1|null|null|
+---+----+----+
```

Unfortunately pure SQL doesn't allow such flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

I guess features is available in Databricks Runtime is on 12.2+. I have tested  same scenarios and attached the screen for your reference .

Creating the table :
[image]

Inserting the value :
[image]

Select the value :
[image]

Comment: Interestingly this doesn't work in raw Spark 3.3.2, on which DBR 12.2 runs. Databricks must be implementing/cherrypicking some extra SQL features. It works fine indeed in raw Spark 3.4.0 thanks to [SPARK-38334](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-38334).